# JAR files created by IntelliJ IDEA do not run

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I wrote a program that spans a few classes in IntelliJ and it works fine when I was testing it in the IDE. However, whenever I follow tutorials to make my project into a .jar executable, it does not run.

The file in the out folder does not run when double-click on it and says "The Java JAR file "projectName.jar" could not be launched.

When opening it from the terminal, I get the error "Could not find or load main class". I used "$ java -jar projectName.jar "

I followed these steps:

1. Open Project Structure, Artifacts and click the (+).
2. Under JAR, from modules with dependencies.
3. Point to the class with my main method and click OK.
4. Click apply and OK to exit.
5. Then I close project structure and open Build and then Build Artifacts...
6. Then I click Build.
7. Navigate to ~/IdeaProjects/projectName/out/artifacts/projectName_jar/projectName.jar

Then I would try to run it but it does not run. My project has both a GUI and can be run from command lines. When I compiled the main method in Terminal, it worked fine, but I need a JAR file. I'm not sure what I should include in the question, since I'm sure that my code is unrelated. I also utilize Maven, not sure if that is related. Are there other things that I should be doing or adding to my project before I build the JAR?

Answer (score 7):

This can be a result of the Manifest being created in the wrong place.

First make sure it is in `src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`

(Intellij sometimes incorrectly places it in `/src/main/java/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`)

Then Make sure the jar is looking for META-INF in the **src** dir NOT in /java OR /resources. This means:

When you set up <kbd>File</kbd>><kbd>Project Structure</kbd>><kbd>Artifacts</kbd>><kbd>+</kbd>><kbd>JAR</kbd>><kbd>From modules with dependencies...</kbd> then your <kbd>Directory for META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</kbd> should end at `src`. Example:

```
ONLY C:\Users\User\StudioProjects\Project\src\
NOT THE PREPOPULATED C:\Users\User\StudioProjects\Project\src\main\java
```

If your <kbd>Project Structure</kbd> jar is already set up change the <kbd>Manifest File</kbd> path to:

```
C:\Users\User\StudioProjects\Project\src\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF
INSTEAD OF C:\Users\User\StudioProjects\Project\src\main\java\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the Main-Class attribute is set. One way to check this is by opening the Jar with a Zip utility and looking for `META-MF/MANIFEST.MF` extract or open that file with a notepad, notepad++ or any document reader. If "Main-Class" is not in their or set to the correct main class you will received the error you have received. Seeing the IntelliJ tutorial it has a Main-Class field when setting up artifact publishing. I have included the link below to the IntelliJ page.

[IntelliJ Creating an Artifact Tutorial](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/)

Comment: The MANIFEST.MF file was created by IntelliJ, so I assume it is correct. The Main-Class is correct, but there are only 2 lines, one is "Manifest-Version: 1.0" and the other is "Main-Class: projectName" Should there be something else there?

Comment: Potentially. The Main-Class attribute must be a fully qualified domain. I.E if your class is in some package or packages.... `com.packagename.ClassName`. See [Package Fundamentals](https://newcircle.com/bookshelf/java_fundamentals_tutorial/packaging) Sections: 7.5. Using Package Members: Qualified Names.  So if you have no packages the attribute is simply the name of the class that has a main method you want to run. Here is the best description for this from Oracles website [Setting an Application's Entry Point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)

Comment: @EricChan I forgot to tag you in my comment. New to stack.