# Unable to run JAR file outside Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, jar, executable-jar

I was able to run the JAR file inside IntelliJ when I do Shift + f10.

However when trying to execute the JAR file from my directory, nothing happens. My META-INF is place as followed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49147689/12973878.

This is my JAR structure
[JAR structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dsoo.png)

File structure Image
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvz4j.png)

Can I know what is the problem here?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @y.bedrov I don't get any error, the GUI just doesn't show up

Comment: Is that JAR executable?

Comment: what command do you run?

Comment: @TechGeek49 yes it is an executable jar file but when i double click on it nothing shows up

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov i was running it directly from my directory as an executable

Comment: I don't understand why you need to open JAR file

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description, I assume you're in a windows environment. Try to run it in terminal. Change the current directory to the location of the file and the terminal command you need to give is:

```
java -jar <jarfilename>
```

Answer (score 0):

After running a build for the project (or a `mvn package`) your jar is placed in `<your_project_path>/target`.

There you will find: `<your_project_name>-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`. Now just open command prompt (on win) / terminal (on mac).

Go to the project path

```
cd <your_project_path>/target
```

and run

```
java -jar <your_project_name>-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Don't forget to check that you have java path in your system `$PATH`
run to verify

```
java -version
```

Comment: What if you wanted to take the jar from the target directory and run it elsewhere i.e run anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

1. Use the `-verbose:class` option when starting the java application to determine if classes are loaded from the correct places.
2. See if there's additional settings in the run configuration of IntelliJ. You'll find it in the upper right corner of the editor window next to the executuin button - dropdown will show `'Edit Configurations'`.
3. If there's really no error at all - are you sure you have the correct starting Class as entry point? You might simply be executing the wrong main method from terminal while
   IntelliJ picks the correct one (look for "main class" in run configuration).